# sending multipart text file as a url parameter

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jsp

Guys I need help sending a text file from jsp page to spring controller. Right now I am sending it as a url param but in controller I am getting null. I have necessary method in controller to parse the text file. I cannot send params as a form variable I must send them as a URL param. I spent few hours but could not find any solution. Please someone help on this , I will greatly appreciate for help. Sorry for poor English. for more info I have added some comments on my code.

```js
//this is how I must pass my params
function urlParam(){

var url="sendParam.html?upldFile"+document.getElementById('upldFile').value();
 
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="file" name="sendFile" id="upldFile">
</div>

<!--I tested using form as a enctype="multipart-form-data" and not passing param as a url then it works, i am getting uploaded file in a controller. but I must send them  as a url param-->

<form id="fileTest" method="post" action="sendParam.html" enctype="multipart-form-data">
<div>
<input type="file" name="sendFile" id="upldFile">
</div>
</form>
```

```js
function urlParam(){

var url="sendParam.html?upldFile"+document.getElementById('upldFile').value();
 
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="file" name="sendFile" id="upldFile">
</div>
```

Comment: `value` is not a function and will only contain the file name which you should also uriEncode if you want it in url. Not sure why you would need that since you are already posting the whole file

Comment: @charlieetfl do you have any examples how this can be achieved?

Comment: Why do you want the file name in url to begin with? The whole file in post already has that

Comment: the post method in form is just for a test and it works if I  send it using form data . but the method has been pre-implemented and the params are being sent as a url params. so I must find a way to send file through url params or something similar

Comment: To send file contents in url just doesn't seem practical but you could use FileReader API to get the file contents and then use `encodeURIComponent()` on it. Note that url's have character limits though...roughly 2000 I think

Comment: @charlietfl how about using url params and also submitting form using post method for submitting text file, do you see any issues doing that?

Comment: Don't see the point when you can post all of it. With that said it's not totally uncommon to have some url params even with a post